# Adding items to an empty linked list C

Tags: c, function, linked-list, return

For a project i am expected to create an empty linked list in one function, and then use that linked list in another function to add items into it. At the moment this is my code for the empty linked list:

```
typedef struct node_t {

int value;
int priority;
struct node_t *next;

}node;

typedef struct priorty_linked_list {

struct name *head;

int current_size;
int max_size;


}priority_list;

typedef node *Node;
typedef priority_list *List;
```

Our instructor gave us the above code, so there shouldnt be anything wrong with it. Next i started with the function create:

```
void create(int max_terms) {


node *head = NULL;
node *next = NULL;
List *current_size = 0;
List *max_size = max_terms;

max_size = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));

printf("The maximum size for the list is %d",max_terms);


}
```

I'm assuming that the next function requires me to use a return function from the create function, but im not sure how. The add function should take the queue created above as a parameter, and not work if i havent created a queue before due to memory allocation.

Any tips or advice on my above code would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: "Our instructor gave us the above code, so there shouldnt be anything wrong with it" - In most cases, this is not true ;)

Comment: List *max_size = max_terms; this isn't right, nor is List *current_size = 0;

Comment: If your instructor gave you the above code, get a new instructor. It has a glaring error. There is no such thing as `struct name`. And an "empty linked list" that carries around data beyond the head pointer (length, maybe a tail pointer, etc) is usually done in its own struct (your `priority_list`) where one simply initialized to and returned by-value from a "create" function. C supports value-return of structures, and I see no sense in dynamically creating the list data structure (you'll be doing enough of that already with the list *nodes*). And *please don't hide pointer types in typedefs*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that in the definition of `priorty_linked_list`, you wanted to write:

```
struct node *head;
```

instead of:

```
struct name *head;
```

[This site has a great explanation](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) and decent implementation that can be used for reference. There are thousands of examples in the Web very similar to what you have to implement. Don't be afraid to Google it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've seen that website and countless others too. But unfortunately none of the ones that I've seen have a function solely for the purpose of creating an empty list, which is my question.

Comment: Are you sure you have to implement `create()` with that exact function signature?

Comment: The description given to me is : Create a new priority queue to store elements, having a max number of elements max_size

Comment: It seems that `create()` should return `priority_list *`, not `void`.

Comment: @user3160152 and you're supposed to use a linked list for this? A top-ended linked list is somewhat counter-intuitive to a size limit sans-embedded system work. Implementing a priority queue as a binary tree in *an array* would make much more sense if "max number of elements" is a condition.

Comment: One more thing, this is absurd: `List *max_size = max_terms;`.

Comment: Yeah, they want two implementations. One being the linked list and the other being a ring buffer. Assuming i return priority_list *, what would the return statement at the bottom of the function be though?

Comment: @user3160152 It would have to `return max_size;`, but please pick better names for your variables. There's nothing that you were asked to do that haven't been done by a few thousand people on the web. By looking at your code I can see that you are completely lost, and the problem is not how to implement a linked list. **The problem is: how to implement a method that returns something, how pointers work, how to allocate dynamic memory, to pass a pointer as a parameter to a function, and so on...**